parents of either of - them/theirs/them's


Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of
them.

Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of
them's.

Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of
theirs.



I think that only 3 is correct. Do you agree?


1 Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of them.


2 *Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of them's.


3 Usually a newly-married couple live with either of the parents of theirs.

(2) is wrong.  There is no such usage them's in any context.
(1) is grammatical.
(3) uses the double possessive and is also grammatical.  This usage, however, is less common than that in (1).

But it would be much simpler (and I would find it more idiomatic) to say with either of their parents.

@KateBunting - maybe I'm being obtuse, but since 'either' means 'one or the other of two', doesn't 'either of their parents', said of a couple, imply (a) they have the same parents (b) those parents live in different locations? I'd say 'either the bride or groom's parents'.

@MichaelHarvey - Not to me! The real meaning is the parents of [either of them], but I think that in casual conversation either of their parents would be understood.

But it's not correct to say "a friend of me", hence 1 should be wrong.

The usage parents of me is indeed rare, so much that Ngram doesn't list it.  Most if not all of us would just say my parents.
I did, however, find a mention in From Big Bang to Big Mystery.
